# What is a Cauchy sequence of definable reals whose limit is undefinable?

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences, constructive-mathematics

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definable_real_number) claims that there exist Cauchy sequences of definable numbers whose limit is not definable. Are there constructive proofs of this? If so, what is an example of a Cauchy sequence of definable reals whose limit is undefinable?

Also, does this claim hold for *definable* sequences of definable numbers? It makes sense to me that such sequences might exist if the Cauchy sequence itself is undefinable (an undefinable sequence of definable numbers), but if the definition of the Cauchy sequence can be specified with a finite amount of information, it seems somewhat paradoxical to me.

Comment: I will have to ask you what do you mean by definable real. Under some interpretations, it is consistent that every real is definable.

Comment: I would use the definition I linked to in the Wikipedia article, possibly with the addendum that the formula used is finite. (not sure if that assumption is already built into the definition of "formula" or not)

Comment: That article is confused and unclear. But if you mean definable "in the set theoretic universe", then it is consistent that *every* real number (and in fact, every object in the universe) is definable. In which case, you cannot find such Cauchy sequence.

Comment: But is every real number definable with a finite definition? If so, wouldn't that make the reals countable? (Since the set of all finite definitions is presumably countable)

Comment: Yes, and no. See http://arxiv.org/abs/1105.4597 (the introduction is very readable).

Comment: So in a model of ZFC where all reals are definable, is Cantor's diagonalization argument for the uncountability of the reals no longer valid for some reason, or is the universe simply inconsistent, since presumably we can prove both "the reals are countable", and "the reals are uncountable"?

Comment: No, Cantor's diagonal argument is always valid. The reals are always uncountable. It's just that the fact that every object in the universe is definable turns out *not* to imply that the universe itself is countable (it is countable in the meta-theory, but internally, it is not countable since it is not even a set).

Comment: @Sintrastes: To make Asaf's comment clear, "uncountable" means "no bijection with $\mathbb{N}$". If we are outside the formal system and looking into a model of the reals, we may see from outside that there are only countably many of them, such as if the model only consists of reals that are definable by some formula inside the language. But this is only valid outside. Inside the formal system we can use the diagonal argument to show that there is no bijection between reals and $\mathbb{N}$, because what we know about reals is strictly less inside than outside. Outside there is a bijection.

Comment: @user2182 (sorry that this comment is so late) I think I understand how the original diagonalization proof is limited to the theory itself showing there isn't a bijection from the definable reals to $\mathbb{N}$, so I suppose what I'm having trouble wrapping my mind around is, why can't we construct a valid diagonaliation proof in the meta-theory showing that the reals are uncountable there? Why do the same arguments not apply? Maybe with my lack of knowledge of model theory understanding this is a fools errand, but do you think you could help point me in the right direction here?

Comment: I.E, why can't we use the diagonalization argument on the (countable) sequence of definable reals, and use that to show no possible bijection with $\mathbb{N}$? (since they are both countable, there should be a bijection from the set of definitions of reals and $\mathbb{N}$)

Comment: @Sintrastes: No problem about the late comment. There is a bijection in the meta-theory. At the same time, the diagonalization proof breaks down because all it shows is that there is no bijection definable in the theory. It does not show that there is no bijection definable in the meta-theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes so you answered your own question essentially. As David noted in his answer any real is the limit of a sequence of rationals, and all rationals are definable, but if you want a definable sequence of reals, then if it has a limit the limit too will be definable (under any reasonable definition of "definable").

Answer (score 0):

Any rational is  certainly definable, and any real is the limit of a sequence of rationals.

Comment: Just because the constituent numbers in a sequence are definable, doesn't mean the sequence is definable. 1 is definable, 0 is definable, but a sequence specified by an infinite number of truly random coin flips can only be described with infinite entropy, and thus is not definable.

Comment: @Sintrastes: I don't know what you mean in your comment but David actually gave at least an answer to your first question...

Comment: ??? I didn't say the sequence was definable! Your first question was just about a sequence of definable reals converging to something not definable. My answer shows there are many such sequences. (Can the sequence itself be definable? It seems unlikely, for the reason you give. A proof would require starting with a few precise definitions...)

Comment: @Sintrastes, your title asks for a sequence of definable reals (not a definable sequence) so if this doesn't answer your question, perhaps you should edit your question to make it more clear.  Also, I understand David's answer.  Pick any real that is undefinable.  Then you can pick a sequence of rationals that converge to it.  Each rational is definable, hence you have a sequence of definable reals...